# Interpreting single p value for three survival curves

Tags: survival

Suppose I use R and the `ggsurvplot()` function to draw three survival curves like this:

[image]

The `ggsurvplot()` then returns a single p value. From what I've read this p value is derived from the score test of the null hypothesis that there are no differences at all between the three survival curves in a cox model.

How can interpret this practically? Is it fair to say the green curve for example is significantly different or in this case superior to the blue or red one? I have a hard time intepreting this because green and red look similar but there seems to be significant difference between blue and the other 2 curves.

Answer (score 2):

All that the score (log-rank) test tells you in this situation is that there is evidence of *some* difference among the 3 survival curves. It doesn't tell you directly which are different.

A simple way to evaluate pairwise differences among the survival curves is to set up a Cox regression model with `group` as a 3-level categorical predictor. The "score" test is for such a model, anyway. You then can do pairwise comparisons among the regression coefficients like you would for any set of multi-category regression coefficients.

In the data you display you might not find any "significant" pairwise differences despite the overall model `p = 0.046`, which is already barely "significant" under the usual `p < 0.05` criterion. And even if you do find such a difference it might not extend well to new data samples. The power in survival analysis comes from the number of events, not the number of total individuals, and you seem to have fewer than 10 events total. You might need on the order of 20 to 30 events to be able to distinguish 3 groups reliably.